# get 50 state abbreviations

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to get the 50 state abbreviations in one column with a usable column name using html5lib.

```
import pandas as pd
import html5lib
fiddy_states = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._state_abbreviations')

fs = fiddy_states[0]
```

Here I can't change the column name:

```
fs.rename(columns={4:'abbv'},inplace=True)
```

Here I can get just the rows I want but I am still sorting out how to just get the 4th column without a usable column name:

```
fs[11:]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC you can use `iloc` to get a column by its index:

```
states=fs.iloc[:,3]
```

Answer (score 6):

the list of states isn't likely to change any time soon, you might be better served just putting them in an array manually:

states = ["AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DC", "DE", "FL", "GA", 
          "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MD", 
          "MA", "MI", "MN", "MS", "MO", "MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ", 
          "NM", "NY", "NC", "ND", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC", 
          "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT", "VT", "VA", "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY"]

unless this is more of a learning exercise, then there are better answers already on the page.

Answer (score 2):

```
['ALABAMA', 'ALASKA', 'ARIZONA', 'ARKANSAS', 'CALIFORNIA', 'COLORADO', 'CONNECTICUT', 'DELAWARE', 'FLORIDA', 'GEORGIA', 'HAWAII', 'IDAHO', 'ILLINOIS', 'INDIANA', 'IOWA', 'KANSAS', 'KENTUCKY', 'LOUISIANA', 'MAINE', 'MARYLAND', 'MASSACHUSETTS', 'MICHIGAN', 'MINNESOTA', 'MISSISSIPPI', 'MISSOURI', 'MONTANA', 'NEBRASKA', 'NEVADA', 'NEW HAMPSHIRE', 'NEW JERSEY', 'NEW MEXICO', 'NEW YORK', 'NORTH CAROLINA', 'NORTH DAKOTA', 'OHIO', 'OKLAHOMA', 'OREGON', 'PENNSYLVANIA', 'RHODE ISLAND', 'SOUTH CAROLINA', 'SOUTH DAKOTA', 'TENNESSEE', 'TEXAS', 'UTAH', 'VERMONT', 'VIRGINIA', 'WASHINGTON', 'WEST VIRGINIA', 'WISCONSIN', 'WYOMING']
```

```
['AL', 'AK', 'AZ', 'AR', 'CA', 'CO', 'CT', 'DE', 'FL', 'GA', 'HI', 'ID', 'IL', 'IN', 'IA', 'KS', 'KY', 'LA', 'ME', 'MD', 'MA', 'MI', 'MN', 'MS', 'MO', 'MT', 'NE', 'NV', 'NH', 'NJ', 'NM', 'NY', 'NC', 'ND', 'OH', 'OK', 'OR', 'PA', 'RI', 'SC', 'SD', 'TN', 'TX', 'UT', 'VT', 'VA', 'WA', 'WV', 'WI', 'WY']
```